# Take the positive value for a primary key in case of duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
Key1   Key2    Value
K11    K21      V1
K11    K21     -V1
K13    K23      V2
K13    K23     -V2
```

Now for example for the same keys K11,K21 combination we have 2 values one negative one positive. How to take only the positive value from this df

Expected output

```
 Key1   Key2    Value
 K11    K21      V1
 K13    K23      V2
```

Note that for my df both keys together are primary key (the combination of Key1 and Key2 has to be unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just `drop_duplicates` with `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values('Value').drop_duplicates(['Key1','Key2'], keep='last')
```

Or you can also do a `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Key1','Key2'], as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: What if we have more than 1 column of val and we want only max of value column. Lets say we had additional columns `Value1`, `Value2`,`Value3` and we wanted to keep the positive value for `Value` column